# How to make html5 video tag open fullscreen automatically

Tags: html, ionic3

I am using html 5 video tag in my ionic project where i has to open a video and play it. Here play, pause and controls are working properly. My requirement is how to open a video file in full screen automatically(i.e default). Here is my code

```
<video autoplay loop controls>
  <source src="{{videoUrl}}" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.. is there any way to do it programmatic in typescript

Comment: Oh! now I see you are in a [ionic] app. So, the language doesn't matter, only the API you have access to does. This means that in a normal web-app (webAPI only), you can't. For ionic, since they have their own API and security rules, maybe they do allow calls to `Element.requestFullscreen` without user interaction (note that it's still not the same as the video's fullscreen you have when clicking on the controls button). But I don't know ionic... sorry. But wouldn't resizing it from CSS to occupy the whole window be enough? (`video{width:100vw;height:100vh}`)

Comment: i tried `(video{width:100vw;height:100vh})` but it didn't worked

Comment: You tried from CSS right? You'll also have to add some `position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:2` etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <video width="100%" height="100%" autoplay>
   <source src="videoUrl" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: A good answer has a better explanation [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)